# Google recaptcha on wordpress throws 500 Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, recaptcha

I followed the tutorial given [here](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/add-google-recaptcha-wordpress/).

I've added `google_recaptcha.php` file in my `/inc` folder of the theme

```
<?php

    $data;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }

    if(!$captcha){
        $data=array('nocaptcha' => 'true');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $google_secret_recaptcha = get_option('recaptcha_secret_key');

    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$google_secret_recaptcha."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if($response.success==false) {
        $data=array('spam' => 'true');
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        $data=array('spam' => 'false');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

I've made it so that I can add google site and secret keyes as settings from wp backend. And they work, since captcha is showing on the comments on the front end.

In my `comments.php` I've added

```
add_filter('comment_form','add_google_captcha');

function add_google_captcha(){
    $google_site_recaptcha = get_option('recaptcha_site_key');
    echo '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="'.$google_site_recaptcha.'"></div>';
}
```

In my `functions.php` I've enqued the recaptcha api

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'google_recaptcha_js', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js','',THEME_VERSION, false);
```

I've tried setting it in the footer, and in the header, and still the same thing happens.

I've also localized my `google_recaptcha.php` so that I can access it in my ajax call

```
wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'ajax_posts', array(
    'ajaxurl'                => $ajaxurl,
    'google_captcha'         => get_template_directory_uri(). '/inc/google_recaptcha.php' ,
    'google_captcha_check'   => esc_html__('Please fill in the required fields and check the captcha', 'mytheme'),
));
```

My on click event looks like:

```
/* Google */
    $("#comment-submit").on('click', function(e){
        console.log('bla');
        var data_2;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax_posts.google_captcha',
            data: $('#commentform').serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.nocaptcha === "true"){
                    data_2=1;
                } else if(data.spam === "true") {
                    data_2=1;
                } else {
                    data_2=0;
                }
                console.log(ajax_posts.google_captcha);
            },
            error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR + ' :: ' + textStatus + ' :: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });

        if( data_2 !== 0 ){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(data_2 == 1){
                $('.form-submit').after('<p class="captcha_alert">'+ajax_posts.google_captcha_check+'</p>');
                    setTimeout(function() { $(".captcha_alert").fadeOut(); }, 4000);
            } else {
                $('.form-submit').after('<p class="captcha_alert">'+ajax_posts.google_captcha_check+'</p>');
                    setTimeout(function() { $(".captcha_alert").fadeOut(); }, 4000);
            }
        } else {
            $("#commentform").submit();
        }
    });
```

When I don't check the recaptcha I get

```
Object {nocaptcha: "true"}
```

Which is ok, the captcha wasn't checked. But if I check it, and fill in the comments (or don't for that matter) I get

> POST http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/google_recaptcha.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Which points to my ajax function (when I expand it in the console, there is: send, m.extend.ajax, (anonymous function) <- this is my ajax call, m.event.dispatch, r.handle)

I checked everything and I don't know what could be wrong. The keys work, because the captcha works. The url in ajax points to the `http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/google_recaptcha.php`, which is ok.

When I check the Form Data from the Network I get the `g-recaptcha-response` and I paste that in the link with the secret key and the IP address and I get

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "missing-input-response",
    "invalid-input-secret"
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Added:

```
error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR + ' :: ' + textStatus + ' :: ' + errorThrown);
}
```

to my ajax, but get only:

```
[object Object] :: error :: Internal Server Error
```

In my console.

**EDIT 2**

Now when I paste my response I get `invalid-input-response` and `invalid-input-secret` :\

Comment: check your error log, `$response.success` should trigger an error.

Comment: You mean in php file? I looked for error log on my server but couldn't find one... I've pasted the url that is in $response variable, and I got `success: false`, as posted above - `invalid-input-response`

Comment: yeah, you probably meant to do `$response->success` instead, but then again you'd have to parse the response first.

Comment: The weird thing is that when I test this on the test server it worked...

Comment: that line won't cause a show stopper, but you'll see some warnings. by the way, are you calling this file directly like you mentioned in the post or are you using wordpress' ajax api?

Comment: ajax api? I'm calling it from the localized script as mentioned in the post...

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Yeah, I totally forgot about ajax handle, and I've used ajax on the same site that way xD Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

I don't know why I didn't do this sooner, as I've done this before many times. I created a handle for ajax

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_google_recaptcha', 'mytheme_ajax_google_recaptcha' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_google_recaptcha', 'mytheme_ajax_google_recaptcha' );

function mytheme_ajax_google_recaptcha() {

    $data;
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }

    if(!$captcha){
        $data=array('nocaptcha' => 'true');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $google_secret_recaptcha = get_option('recaptcha_secret_key');

    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$google_secret_recaptcha."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if($response.success==false) {
        $data=array('spam' => 'true');
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        $data=array('spam' => 'false');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

}
```

And then in my ajax I just added, instead of `url`, `action: 'google_recaptcha',`

And it works now :D